# How can I extract a total count or sum of agents who made their first sale in a specified month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to extract some data out of a large table of data in Excel. The table consists of the month, the agent's name, and either a 1 if they made a sale or a 0 if they did not.

What I would like to do is plug in a Month value into one cell, then have it spit out a count of how many agents made their first sale that month.

[`Sample Data and Input Output area`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn9Gs.png)

I found success by creating a secondary table for processing a minif and matching to agent name, then countif in that table's data how many sales months matched the input month. However I would like to not have a secondary table and do this all  in one go.

```
=IF(MINIFS(E2ERawData[Date Group],E2ERawData[Agent],'Processed Data'!B4,E2ERawData[E2E Participation],1)=0,"No Sales",MINIFS(E2ERawData[Date Group],E2ERawData[Agent],'Processed Data'!B4,E2ERawData[E2E Participation],1))
=COUNTIFS(ProcessedData[Month of First E2E Sale],H4)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Formula in column F is:

```
=MAX(0;COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8;E3;$C$2:$C$8;1)-SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8;"<"&E3;$C$2:$C$8;1;$B$2:$B$8;IF($A$2:$A$8=E3;$B$2:$B$8))))
```

This is how it works (we'll use `01/03/2022` as example)

1. `COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8;E3;$C$2:$C$8;1)` This counts how many 1 there are for the proper month (in our example this part will return 2)
2. `COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8;"<"&E3;$C$2:$C$8;1;$B$2:$B$8;SI($A$2:$A$8=E3;$B$2:$B$8))` will count how many 1 you got in **previous** months of the **same** agents (in our example, it will return 1)
3. Result from step 2, because it's an array formula, we sum up using `SUM()` (in our example, this return 1)
4. We do result from step 1 **minus** result from step 3 (so we get 1)
5. Finally, everything is inside a MAX function to avoid negative results (February would return -1 because there were no sales at all and agent B did a sale on January, so it would return -1. To avoid this, we force Excel to show biggest value between 0 and our calculation)

**NOTE:** Because it's an array formula, depending on your Excel version maybe you must introduce pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Looks like this didn't work exactly how I needed it to and the results were not accurate when I manually calculated the results from the data. 

I need to get a count of how many agents made their very first sale in a given month. So this formula needs to be able to look through all of the entries and add to a total count if the agent being inspected has never made a sale previously.  This Data spans from 1/1/21 - 12/1/22 and there are about 500 agents each month with either a 1 or a 0 to indicate if they made a sale or not that month.

Answer (score 2):

If one has got access to the newest functions:

[image]

```
=LET(X,UNIQUE(C3:C9),VSTACK({"Month","Total of First time sales"},HSTACK(X,BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,SUM((C3:C9=a)*(MINIFS(C3:C9,D3:D9,D3:D9,E3:E9,1)=C3:C9)))))))
```

Comment: I do have Office 365 and I do have access to your suggested functions. However I am getting a #NAME error

Comment: I adapted the code you provided. I have two tables. One with all the data of all agents each month and if they have a sale or not. The Second table is strictly used to summarize the first table to count the total of agents who made their first sale that month.

=LET(X,UNIQUE(E2ERawData[Date Group]),VSTACK({"Month","Total of First time sales"},HSTACK(X,BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,SUM((E2ERawData[Date Group]=a)*(MINIFS(E2ERawData[Date Group],E2ERawData[Agent],E2ERawData[Agent],E2ERawData[E2E Participation],1)=E2ERawData[Date Group])))))))